# how to run the Django server as a windows service

Tags: python

The goal is running the Django server as a windows startup via autostart windows service.so I need to write a python module that adds a service to windows services contains "python manage.py runserver" or something like this.
I use [this toturial](http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) and add services to windows services but it doesn't run successfully. error is here:

```
---------------------------
Services
---------------------------
Windows could not start the Test Service service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

-- also I found something like this to run django server via python module:

```
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "service.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    args = ['name', 'runserver', '127.0.0.1:8000']
    execute_from_command_line(args)
```

any idea to make a windows service that runs the Django server automatically at startup or any other way to do this?

-- I don't want to create a .bat file and put in startup.

Comment: It is best to use a proper web server (IIS, Apache, etc) and start that as a service. Django development server is, well, for development only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the django windows tools, it quite elaborate, but you need this package installed in your project virtual environment

```
pip install django-windows-tools
```

and then add to your installed apps.

You could read the complete documentation here on pypi https://pypi.org/project/django-windows-tools/

Here is another snippet showing how to achieve that https://gist.github.com/mikofski/11028442

I hope it works perfectly